# Include three.js into wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, three.js, wordpress-theming

So basically what I am trying to achieve is simple:

I want to use three.js with my current custom wordpress theme.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find any information on how to do so.
I enqueue all my scripts via functions.php, I guess that is the default approach.

Since three.js has to be loaded with "type=module" I can not get it to work properly, and it seems as if it has to be done in another way. Should the import statements take place in my themes header? I always think that it is bad practice... And how can I then write my three.js code into an external js file?

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since three.js has to be loaded with "type=module"

That is actually not true. `three.js` provides an ESM (`three.module.js`) and two UMD builds (`three.js` and `three.min.js`). Including the minified UMD build in your wordpress theme should solve the issue. The following lives example uses this build file:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;
let mesh;

init();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setAnimationLoop( animation );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animation( time ) {

    mesh.rotation.x = time / 2000;
    mesh.rotation.y = time / 1000;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.130.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The getting started guide states: "any script that references the library must use type="module" as shown below:", that is why I thought that it was necessary. Anyways, your solution works great. I added the script into my functions.php as normal and everything works great! Thanks.

Comment: I believe this solution is now out of date, and I would be interested to hear how to properly integrate threejs and wp at this time